# Keep Empty Factor Levels During Aggregation

Tags: r, data.table

I'm using data.table to aggregate values, but I'm finding that when the "by" variable has a level not present in the aggregation, it is omitted, even if it is specified in the factor levels.

The code below generates a data.table with 6 rows, the last two of which only have one of the two possible levels for f2 nested within f1. During aggregation, the {3,1} combination is dropped.

```
set.seed(1987)
dt <- data.table(f1 = factor(rep(1:3, each = 2)),
                 f2 = factor(sample(1:2, 6, replace = TRUE)),
                 val = runif(6))

str(dt)

Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  6 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ f1 : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 1 2 2 3 3
 $ f2 : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 2 2 1 2 2
 $ val: num  0.383 0.233 0.597 0.346 0.606 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 

dt

   f1 f2       val
1:  1  1 0.3829077
2:  1  2 0.2327311
3:  2  2 0.5965087
4:  2  1 0.3456710
5:  3  2 0.6058819
6:  3  2 0.7437177

dt[, sum(val), by = list(f1, f2)] # output is missing a row

   f1 f2        V1
1:  1  1 0.3829077
2:  1  2 0.2327311
3:  2  2 0.5965087
4:  2  1 0.3456710
5:  3  2 1.3495996

# this is the output I'm looking for:
   f1 f2        V1
1:  1  1 0.3829077
2:  1  2 0.2327311
3:  2  2 0.5965087
4:  2  1 0.3456710
5:  3  1 0.0000000 # <- the missing row from above
6:  3  2 1.3495996
```

Is there a way to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you expect that data.table will compute sums for all combinations of  f1 and f2?

If this what you want you should add missings rows to the original data before grouping sum. For example:

```
setkey(dt, f1, f2)
# omit "by = .EACHI" in data.table <= 1.9.2
dt[CJ(levels(f1), levels(f2)), sum(val, na.rm=T),
   allow.cartesian = T, by = .EACHI]
##     f1 f2        V1
## 1:  1  1 0.3829077
## 2:  1  2 0.2327311
## 3:  2  1 0.3456710
## 4:  2  2 0.5965087
## 5:  3  1 0.0000000   ## <- your "missing row" :)
## 6:  3  2 1.3495996
```

Comment: I expected this behavior because I've seen it in other functions. For example: `table(dt$f1, dt$f2)` produces the results for all combinations.